# VS Code Gives Me a "Module Not found './SomeFile.module.css' Error ... But Takes me to the File?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm getting a VS Code error (which might really be coming from Typescript or ES Lint) complaining that a CSS import I have isn't found.

[image: Error example]

The error says "Module Not Found":

[image: Error details]

... but what's so weird is that I can `COMMAND + click` (`CTRL + click` on Windows) on the file (*even though* it has a red underline), and VS Code takes me directly to it.

In other words, VS Code can find the file when I say "take me to this file" ... but it can't find the file just during the normal course of validation.  My best guess is that Typescript/ES Lint/something else is responsible for the error ... but I have no idea how to tell whatever is responsible "the file is there, stop freaking out!"

P.S. This is not a site-wide issue with CSS files; I have plenty of other CSS Module imports that aren't getting any errors.

Comment: I sincerely doubt ESLint has anything to do with this. Unless you happen to have any custom or third-party plugins that for some reason try to validate imports or something. Even then it'd be incredibly odd for such a plugin to exist. ESLint parses the AST of the code and looks for patterns there. Imports are not something that usually falls under the purview of linting. Does the error point you at an ESLint rule? It should say something like "eslint (rule-goes-here)" if it does.

Comment: All I see is what's in the screenshot.  And I have no specific reason to blame ES Lint ... I'm just trying to reconcile VS Code being able to go to the file just fine, with it's claim that it can't find that same file.  The only way that makes sense to me is that if VS Code itself *can* find the file, but some other tool (eg. Typescript?) can't.

Comment: Maybe checkout the root path (baseUrl)

Comment: Since it's a relative path (ie. it starts with `./`) I wouldn't think `baseUrl` would be applicable.